# How to fix problems with apache2 after installing SSL certificate?

Tags: server, ssh, apache2

I have Apache/2.4.41 installed on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. This is on a cloud VM.

The server has PHP 7.4, and PHP 7.3 installed. Phyton was deleted completely by mistake and then installed back. Then, I tried to recover as many libraries as possible. Not sure if there are still some missing.

I installed an SSL certificate from let'sencrypt. Since the installation, I've been having trouble accessing the site. Sometimes the browser says the site is unreachable. To fix it, I have to ssh the server and restart apache by using `sudo service apache2 restart`. After that, the site becomes reachable again.

```
sudo apache2ctl configtest
Syntax OK
```

What can be wrong with it? I don't want to lose my configutation files in case I have to reinstall apache2. It seems that I have to restart apache2 every day.

After trying solution from @Matigo, cleared error.log, and restarted apache2:

cat /var/log/apache2/error.log

```
[Sun Mar 07 22:38:42.177067 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1566] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Mar 07 22:38:42.264574 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 9359] AH00163: Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.1j configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Mar 07 22:38:42.264636 2021] [core:notice] [pid 9359] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

sudo systemctl status apache2

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-03-08 23:25:02 UTC; 14h ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 9348 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 9359 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 07 22:38:42 bhub systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Mar 07 22:38:42 bhub systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Mar 08 23:25:02 bhub systemd[1]: apache2.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 08 23:25:02 bhub systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: Did you have a look in the apach2 log files? what error log is saying?

Comment: @mestia I did, but I don't really understand much of it. I have included it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since after apache2 failed, restarting the service fixed the problem; I added this lines before [Install] in /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service:

```
# Added
Restart=on-failure
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
# Added
```

This fixed my problem. I hope it helps someone else with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of your Apache log, there are a couple of things that should be looked at.

First, let's get rid of those `Unable to load dynamic library` issues by re-installing those libraries and ensuring they're enabled:

1. Reinstall the libraries:

   ```
   sudo apt install php-xmlrpc php-xsl php-imagick
   ```
2. Ensure they're enabled:

   ```
   sudo phpenmod xmlrpc 
   sudo phpenmod xsl 
   sudo phpenmod imagick
   ```

For the `Module X already loaded in Unknown on line 0`, this is probably a duplicate loading of [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) in `php.ini`.

1. Check that your `php.ini` does not have `xdebug.so` in either of the following lines:

   ```
   extension=
   zend_extension=
   ```
2. Confirm in your `/etc/php/7.x/apache2` and `/etc/php/7.x/cli/` directories that the `php.ini` files do not have `xdebug.so` specified more than once. (be sure to replace `7.x` with the version of PHP that you're running. If you're running PHP 5.x, you'll need to look in `etc/php5` for these directories.)

As for the SSL issues, there is nothing in the log specifically pointing to why it's not loading properly, so you may need to update your question to include an updated `error.log` result after fixing the above issues, assuming that solving the above issues does not resolve the underlying issue with your Apache installation

Comment: Hi @Matigo, I tried your solution and the libraries have been installed if they were not already. sudo phpenmod xmlrpc returns
```WARNING: Module xmlrpc ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.4/mods-available```
```WARNING: Module xmlrpc ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.3/mods-available```
I also looked into php.ini on both folders and they don't have ```xdebug.so```

Comment: Has your server been upgraded over multiple versions of Ubuntu and multiple versions of PHP? Because it sounds like something is "missing" ...

Comment: the server has PHP 7.4, and PHP 7.3 installed. Phyton was deleted completely from the PC by mistake and then installed back. Then, I tried to recover as many libraries as possible. Not sure if there are still some missing.

Comment: That’s the sort of important information that really should be part of the question as it adds context to the source of the problems …